# Error when trying to change temporary URL to live on Wordpress, using Heart Internet domain reference

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I've built a site on Heart Internet using what they call a domain reference (IPaddress/site.com/, a temporary URL), but now want to change to a live URL. The person who owns the domain has pointed it to my IP address, and the lookup for that domain proves it has been successful. When I try to visit the page, I get a "This page has been reserved for future use" message.

I've tried putting in a dummy index.html into the root folder, but I still get the same message.

I've changed my Wordpress settings to the live URL, but when I save I get an error "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-login.php on this server", and have to into the database and manually change it back.

If I manually search and replace all the URLs in the database and replace them for the live URL, I get the same problem (downloading the db, replacing the links in Dreamweaver, and reimporting into the db).

Any advice for someone quite desperate who has been searching high and low on the internet for help?

Answer (score 0):

I raised a ticket with Heart, and it turns out you have to use the exact same URL in the domain reference as you're going to use later when you make it live. I thought that any temporary one would work, but no. Pointed site correctly to the right hosting package, transferred site, changed home & url in the database manually, and it's finally live.